# How to proxy a websocket connection in browser

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, websocket

Is there any way to proxy a WebSocket connection in browser JS?
I know there are modules to do it in node.js but is it possible to do write it as code that a browser can execute?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like nginx https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/